# Using VPN to hide TOR

Tags: anonymity, security, vpn

I've read discussions where some people advocate starting VPN first, then TOR and other recommend start TOR, then run the VPN.

Whichever way I connect, if I go to whoer.net or stilllistener.com to check my anonymity they always show the IP of the last TOR node.  Never the IP of the VPN.

Is this normal?

IF at least one method should show the VPN IP, what do I need to check / configure to make it happen please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: A VPN isn't required at all. Or recommended.

Comment: May I ask why please?

Comment: https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/tor-misconception/blob/master/README.md I've been trying to document silly things that people believe because they read it on the internet, often while being sold a product.

Comment: Thank you.  I read the TOR->VPN or VPN->TOR before posting my question.  I didn't really understand it.  I'll revisit it, and check out the second link too.  Once again - thank you for your help.

Comment: To be honest all the answers on that other post are awful, I'll add one later if I remember...it'll just be a summary of my github link though.